# Make return URL for getting a response from bank/paymentgateway

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I need to create a return url which I have given to a payment gateway in which they will post their response parameters:

```
status
customerReferenceNo    
referenceNo
merchantId
amount
checkSum
```

to the URL I given. All I want is an HTML page which could accept this parameters and store them to a database, the database part I can do it.

But the php code for accepting their values,I cant do that.i dont know whether they are using POST or GET:

```
status-4N
customerReferenceNo    -  30An
referenceNo  - 32 AN
merchantId  - 10AN
amount  - 9.2AN
checkSum - 64AN
```

This are the parameters they given in their documentation and they have also given respective field specification (I don't know what field specs is).

The status '0' will be successful transaction and if its a negative value, it's a failed transaction.

```
 <?php
    require("./connect.php");

    if (count($_GET)==0 && count($_POST)==0)
    {  
    ?> 
         <h1 style="font-weight:bold; font-family:'RobotoThin' align='center';">ERROR. NO DATA FOUND</h1>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
        {

         $status    = $_REQUEST['Status'];
         $essrefno= $_REQUEST['TransactionId'];
         $ref_no= $_REQUEST['ReferenceNo']; 

         $sql = "update `tablename` set `ess_ref_no`= '$essrefno',status='$status' where ref_no ='$ref_no'";

         mysql_query($sql);
         }
         if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
        {

         $status    = $_REQUEST['Status'];
         $essrefno= $_REQUEST['TransactionId'];
         $ref_no= $_REQUEST['ReferenceNo'];

          //echo $status+$essrefno+$ref_no;
         $sql = "update `tablename` set `ess_ref_no`= '$essrefno',status='$status' where ref_no ='$ref_no'";

         mysql_query($sql);
         }
        //echo $sql;
    ?>
    <?php
        if ($status==0 )
        {
    ?>
            <h1 style="font-weight:normal; font-family:'RobotoThin';">Your transaction is successful and your transaction reference no for any further communication is  <?php echo $ref_no; ?> .</h1>
     <?php
        }
        else
        {
     ?>
            <h1 style="font-weight:normal; font-family:'RobotoThin';">Your transaction failed and your transaction reference no for any further communication is  <?php echo $ref_no; ?>.</h1>
     <?php
        } 
    }
?>
```

This is the PHP I have made but it's not working. Moreover I have given something.html page to them and I don't know how this PHP be integrated to that HTML page using JavaScript or something? Is there someone who could help me?

Comment: Since you are using _REQUEST, it doesn't matter if they POST or GET the data. BOth wil show up in _REQUEST. Remove the `if _SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'` bit though. Aside from that you can't expect us to answer your questions since we dont even have the documentation that you have. How about just doing a print_r($_REQUEST); to see what data they are sending you?..

Comment: Ok.this is php file.but i have given a .html file to them to post their reponse.How to integrate this php file into an html?

Comment: http://pdfShare.it/doc/5HO444O5D  and this is the documentation

Comment: When payment is complete, the paying customer is usually redirected to the url you gave your bank. Most of the time the transaction id and such is in the url, which means its in $_GET in php. I do feel though, that you lack the knowledge to implement financial transactions yourself, I really suggest getting some help to do this right or you might be in trouble later.. (with payments, security is a big deal..). For one: your code is wide open for sql injection. Anyone can wipe your entire database with easy... Really, get help from someone..

Comment: thanks .Yeah :) But this one is for study purpose.The actual implemetation is done by my senior and I wanted myself to test this using my own code and I cant do that.And the lack of knowledge hmmm i dont think one will be knowing for A to Z about a stuff.this is the way people learn things ;)

Comment: Good :) Learning is always a great thing. For your studies though, look into: mysqli, prepared statements and sql injection. Its very important (mysqli is the function "suite" that enables you to use "prepared statements", which will help you avoid "sql injection"). Very important stuff to know, otherwise everything you code will be an open door for hackers. Good luck with your studies!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superglobal $_REQUEST will contain both POST as GET data, so don't worry too much (yet) if they POST or GET the data.

Do a `var_dump($_REQUEST);` to see the data that's been posted. Should be easy from that point on.

Comment: Yeah.thank you I'll try this.but before that,I have a php file.and I have given them an html page as reponnse url.Is there someway I could add this php to that html file?